# Get a multiple level dropdown to only appear at a certain browser width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm trying to create a list of links that are visible on desktop and tablet but when you resize it down to mobile size it becomes part of a multilevel drop down. I've got it to work but only when I refresh the page.

I've tried working two different pieces of js that I've found on tutorials and I'm sure there would be a simpler way of accomplishing this.

html

```
       <ul class="accordion">
            <li>
                <a href="#">America</a>
                <ul>    
                    <li><a href="#">New York</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">San Fransisco</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Washington</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Antarctica</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Afro-Eurasia</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Amsterdam</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Paris</a></li>
                    <li><a class="#">Stockholm</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Australia</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Melbourne</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Perth</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sydney</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Google</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

js for the assessing the browser width

```
(function($){
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var current_width = $(window).width();
    if(current_width < 480){
      jQuery('body').addClass("mobile");
    }
  });

  $(window).resize(function(){
    var current_width = $(window).width();
    if(current_width < 480){
      jQuery('body').addClass("mobile");
    }
  });

})(jQuery);
```

js for the dropdown

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.mobile .accordion ul').hide();
    $('.mobile .accordion li a').click(
        function() {
            var openMe = $(this).next();
            var mySiblings = $(this).parent().siblings().find('ul');
            if (openMe.is(':visible')) {
                openMe.slideUp('normal');  
            } else {
                mySiblings.slideUp('normal');  
                openMe.slideDown('normal');
            }
          }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   setResize();
   resizeCheck();
});
function createMobile() {
   $('.mobile .accordion ul').hide();
   $('.mobile .accordion li a').unbind("click");
   $('.mobile .accordion li a').click(
       function() {         
           var openMe = $(this).next();
           var mySiblings = $(this).parent().siblings().find('ul');
           if (openMe.is(':visible')) {
               openMe.slideUp('normal');  
           } else {
               mySiblings.slideUp('normal');  
               openMe.slideDown('normal');
           }          
         }
   );
};
function resizeCheck() {
   var current_width = $(window).width();      
   if(current_width < 480){
     if(!$('body').hasClass('mobile'))
     {
         $('body').addClass("mobile");
     }
     createMobile();
   }
   else {
       if($('body').hasClass('mobile'))
       {
           $('body').removeClass('mobile');
       }
   }
};
function setResize() {  
   $(window).resize(function() {
       resizeCheck();
   });
};
function removeResize() {
   $(window).unbind('resize');
};
```

see working example on
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9AR2Y/1/)

Comment: thanks for the reply, unfortunately this doesn't work. It does change into a dropdown nav when it reaches the specified height but you can't open the dropdown, as when you click on a li it scrolls down the ul inside it and then instantly scrolls it back up. Also when you scroll out from 480px it stays as a dropdown and doesn't revert back into a list of visible links.

Comment: where do you create the dropbox? i can't find it on the js code

Comment: I've made changes to my question so it is easier to view which piece of js does what.

Comment: see the my edit man. it's supposed to be perfect now.
if it's working well just don't forget to accept the answer ;)